# Can Spring security SAML be used to configure IDPs at Runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'ld like to implement `SSO` using `SAML 2.0` in my web applications. I have seen `spring-security-saml` and example of [spring boot application](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample). There are a couple of things I wanted to know after I went through the sample:

1. Is it possible to take Idp Url and certificates at run time and use spring saml to validate against that `Idp`? (*So essentially I do not want to predefine any of the `Idp` related details and take an input from admin user to configure `Idp`*)
2. Is metadata of `Idp` a necessary field or Is it possible that if `IDP` is not reachable directly from the `SP` then also it can just create a `SAMLRequest` to the `Idp` `Url` provided?